# React & Redux - TypeError state is not iteratable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to add objects to an array which is present in my Redux. The code works fine if I don't add redux-persist, but after adding redux-persist i get a TypeError that state is not Iterateable. I want to run the code with redux-persist. Is there any way to do that ?

My Store code before adding redux-persist :

```
import rootReducer from './reducer';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    {},
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);

export default store;
```

Reducer.js Code is as follows :

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    reduxArray : []
}

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case 'POPULATEARRAY':
            return ({
                 ...state,
                reduxArray : [action.payload , ...state.reduxArray]
            })

        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

Action.js Code is as follows :

```
export function Populate(data) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({ type: 'POPULATEARRAY', payload: data  })
    }
}
```

My Store code after adding redux-persist :

```
import rootReducer from './reducer';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
}


const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
const store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
const persistor = persistStore(store);
export { store, persistor };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function ins `Reducer.js` is incorrect. The `state` parameter of that function is an array, so doing some thing like this

```
{
    ...state,
    reduxArray : [action.payload , ...state.reduxArray]
}
```

will cause error as `...state` doesn't have a key. May be this is the shape that you want

```
case 'POPULATEARRAY': 
    return [action.payload , ...state.reduxArray]
```